# Show open/save dialog java

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm trying to save and load `.txt` files on my program. I've got methods to read and write the files, but I want the user to be able to choose which name and where the files will be saved using the open/save forms. I've done this so far.

```
JButton btnLoad = new JButton("Carregar");

btnCarregar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    private Component modalToComponent;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

        if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(modalToComponent) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        }           
    }
});
```

Right, this actually opens the form, but after that, I don't know where and how use my methods to load the text. I guess, I should use `file` since it's the selected file, but when I send this file to my methods, it just doesnt work. Any example would be appreciated. Thanks before hand!

Comment: Ho does it not work? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Without your showing how you may be using it wrong, complete with any and all error codes, it's hard to know how to give you advice.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy-paste, and see the same error as you. You say: `it just doesnt work`. What exactly doesn't work? The save part?, open part? In any case, provide those codes too please.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to specify exactly what failed, the problem was - i already solved it - it would send NullPointerException. The problem I had is that I wasn't using the selected file to write/read whatever, I was using something else. Anyway thanks for the fast answers and your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method from the point where the user has selected a file to open (in the if part of the `actionPerformed` method). So if your reading method is called `openFile` and accepts a `File` parameter, you can call 'openFile(file)` as the second statement in your if block:

```
if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(modalToComponent) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    openFile(file);
}
```

A simple example of an `openFile` method to handle opening a file (in this case by only printing the contents) could look like this:

```
private void openFile(final File inputFile) {
    try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("line: " + line);
            // todo: handle line.
        }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // todo: handle exception.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't using the file from the selection, thats why it crashed, sometimes the simpliest things are the hardest ones to see.